# Rejection Email to the contributor or author from admin

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have created one custom form in admin post editor, to send email templates to authors. I'm facing problem during ajax call that isn't redirecting to the page which I need and getting message post updated when selected template and click on send option

```
<div id="custom-meta-files" class="row"> 
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <label style="" for="reject_email_template">Template Name</label>
           <?php

            // The Query
            $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'email-templates', 
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            ));
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>
                <select style="display: block;width: 100%;margin: 10px 0;" name="_reject_email" class="form-control" id="reject_email_template">
                    <?php 
                    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                        $the_query->the_post(); 
                        echo '<option value="'.get_the_ID().'">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
                    } ?>
                </select>
                    <?php 
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                } else {
                    // no posts found
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="reject-email-btn btn btn-primary" style="border:none; padding: 6px 1rem;color: #fff; background: #0085ba;text-decoration: none;">Send</button>
    </form>
    <div id="fromPartsTable"></div>
</div>
```

save posts in custom fields database

```
 add_action('admin_init','event_meta_init');
 function event_meta_init(){

foreach (array('post') as $type){
    add_meta_box('my_all_meta', 'Reject Email', 'my_meta_setup', $type, 'normal', 'high');
}



add_action('save_post','my_meta_save');}

function my_meta_setup(){
global $post;
// using an underscore, prevents the meta variable
// from showing up in the custom fields section
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_post',TRUE);
// instead of writing HTML here, lets do an include
include(MY_THEME_FOLDER . '/metafields/events-fields.php');
// create a custom nonce for submit verification later
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="my_meta_noncename" value="' .    wp_create_nonce(__FILE__) . '" />';
 }

function my_meta_save($post_id){
   // authentication checks
   // make sure data came from our meta box
 if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['my_meta_noncename'],__FILE__)) return    $post_id;
// check user permissions
if ($_POST['post_type'] == 'page'){
    if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) return $post_id;
}else{
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) return $post_id;
}

$current_data = get_post_meta($post_id, '_post', TRUE);

$new_data = $_POST['_post'];

my_meta_clean($new_data);

if ($current_data){
    if (is_null($new_data)) delete_post_meta($post_id,'_post');
    else update_post_meta($post_id,'_post',$new_data);
}elseif (!is_null($new_data)){
    add_post_meta($post_id,'_post',$new_data,TRUE);
}

  return $post_id;
}
function my_meta_clean(&$arr){
   if (is_array($arr))  {
       foreach ($arr as $i => $v){

       if (is_array($arr[$i])){
            my_meta_clean($arr[$i]);
            if (!count($arr[$i])){
                unset($arr[$i]);
            }
        }else{
            if (trim($arr[$i]) == ''){
                unset($arr[$i]);

            }
        }
    }

    if (!count($arr)){
        $arr = NULL;
    }
}
}
```

My ajax script is

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
    function rejection_email(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/rejection-email/",
            data : {eid:$('#reject_email_template').val()},
            success: function(data) {
                var result = data
                $('#fromPartsTable').html(result);

            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    }
    $('.reject-email-btn').click(function(e) {
        rejection_email();
    });
})(jQuery);
```